# How to use '&' in Expression Blend TextBlock?

Tags: c#, wpf-controls, expression-blend

In textblock, I want to write '`Collection of Document & Online Transaction`'. How could I write '&' in blend? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the [XML entity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) `&amp;` - XAML is XML so follows the same rules as any other XML document.